# RxJS - Complete observation when provided expression is true

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm looking for an existing operator that could filter my observable, and if it's true, the observable will complete.

I can do it like so:

```
obs$.pipe(
  filter(value => value),
  first()
);
```

But I'm wondering if there's a way to combine `filter` and `first` operators together.

I thought `skipUntil` would be a good choice, but it skips until an *observable* emits, and not until a true value has been passed.

Comment: Small nitpick, filter and first are not called pipes but operators.

Comment: @tomvangreen True. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I had to pay more attention to the [docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/first.html) of `first`, which does exactly what I was looking for.

```
// RxJS v6+
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

const source = from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

//emit first item to pass test
const example = source.pipe(first(num => num === 5));

//output: "First to pass test: 5"
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val =>
  console.log(`First to pass test: ${val}`)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`takeWhile`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-takeWhile) operator:

```
const $observableThatCompletes = obs$.takeWhile((value) => true !== value);
```

The resulting observable will complete as soon as `value` is `true`.

*You can use `!value` instead of `true !== value` if you want to match all 'truthy' values.*

Comment: It's the opposite of what I wanted. It returns a value as long as the condition is true. Once it's falsy, it completes. Please look at my answer, `first` is what I was looking for.

Comment: @EliyaCohen Ah I see. Another equivalent closer to my answer would then be: `$obs.skipWhile((v) => 5 !== v).first()`, but your solution is actually cleaner.